# OpenStack Swift

Tags: vps, debian, openvz

Привет.

Мне необходимо установить **OpenStack Swift** (для обучения и тестирования).Для этого я использую официальную [документацию](http://docs.openstack.org/developer/swift/development_saio.html).

Вопрос у меня в следующем:

Что необходимо выбрать на обычном **VPS** с виртуализацией **OpenVZ** для хранилища,"Partition for storage" или "Loopback device for storage"?

И есть ли возможность установки на **VPS**, если да, то есть ли зависимость от виртуализации?

Скажу заранее я девелопер, не системный администратор и это лично для меня в обучающих целях. Поэтому решил уточнить, прежде чем начинать.

Answer (score 1):

"Partition for storage" - это если распределить для Свифта отдельный раздел (партицию) на диске.

"Loopback device for storage" - это когда Свифтовый раздел хранится в отдельном файле, как во многих виртуальных машинах. Полезен тем, что его можно переносить.

А вот этого:

> И есть ли возможность установки наVPS, если да, то есть ли зависимостьот виртуализации?

я не понял! В каком смысле? Кластер облака на виртуальный сервер засунуть? Вполне можно, если хозяин ВС не против. Но это же попытка засунуть один жигуль в багажник другого, чтобы получить в результате мерседес!

Comment: Спасибо. Мне это необходимо для обучения. А VPS сам по себе небольшой сервер. И устанавливаемая мною версия SAIO (по ссылке вверху) как раз для разработчика. Из ответа получается, что зависимости от типа виртуализации нету? Просто у меня не создаются не Partition не Loopback на VPS с виртуализацией OpenVZ.

Comment: Loopback-то как раз и должен работать, потому что это виртуальная ФС в контейнере, т.е. в файле, и ей как-то пофиг куда этот файл засунут. Если это не работает, то это проблема скорее, двойной виртуализации. Лично я ни разу в жизни не пробовал запустить одну ВМ внутри другой. Думаю, что и не получится.

Comment: Получится ))

Comment: ArcherGodson, если есть положтельный опыт в этом деле - предоставьте нам, несведущим. Теоретически это наверное возможно, только представить себе не могу - зачем???

Comment: в документации сказано: Create guest virtual machine from the Ubuntu image. Вот я и делаю :)

Comment: Ну так сделайте! И скриншоты - в студию!

Comment: Даже если это работает, всё равно не понимаю - зачем???